# Multiple layout are not working in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

```
<Router history={history}>
    <Route>
            <MainLayout>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path={ROUTES.HOME} component={Login} />
                    <Route path={ROUTES.LOGIN} component={Login} />
                    <Route path={ROUTES.SIGN_UP} component={SignUp} />
                </Switch>
            </MainLayout>
        </Route>
</Router>
```

It only renders signup component even when the route is changed to login. Attaching Main Layout and toolbar component below

```
const MainLayout = (props) => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Toolbar />
            {props.children}
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

const Toolbar = () => {
    return (
        <header>
            <nav>
                <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
                <Link to="/signup">Register</Link>
            </nav>
        </header>
    );
};
```

Comment: looks strange. Why you need `Route` for layout? Just wrap your switch with your layouts, without Route.

Comment: @demkovych, I did that but there's another issue, I've edited the question

Comment: Worth to see values of those ROUTES.* constants

Comment: export const ROUTES = {
  HOME: '/',
  SIGNUP: '/signup',
  LOGIN: '/login'
}

Comment: `<Route path={ROUTES.HOME} component={Login} exact strict />` and add `exact` to rest routes. And your HOME AND LOGIN routes has the same component

Comment: Do you have, maybe, some redirects in the Login component? BTW, I would recommend to put the HOME route in the end of the chain or use `exact` prop

Comment: @demkovych, it only renders login component at starting and after that it does not render any component

Comment: @IgorBukin, I have a toolbar component in MainLayout which contains a link to login and signup, but it does not render any component on clicking it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should has a structure like:

```
<Router history={history}>
  <MainLayout>
    <Switch>
      <Route path={ROUTES.HOME} exact strict component={Login} />
      <Route path={ROUTES.LOGIN} exact component={Login} />
      <Route path={ROUTES.SIGN_UP} exact component={SignUp} />
    </Switch>
  </MainLayout>
</Router>
```

Comment: I mean you don't need additional `Route` wrapper.

Comment: instead of putting the `exact` prop everywhere you could just move the home route "/" to the bottom of the list. All the other routes rarely fall into collision

Comment: @demkovych I've tried this as well, the main layout gets rerendered but the {props.children} does not render after clicking on the link

Comment: then the problem with MainLayout or route components itself

Comment: @demkovych, I've attached the main layout and toolbar component as well in the question. can you check that edited question

Comment: try to use `NavLink` instead: `<NavLink to="/login">Login</NavLink>`

Comment: so, after you clicked on the Link it shows a new url but nothing happens?

Comment: @demkovych Still, it doesn't work. Any other solution that I can try.

Comment: @demkovych, Yes it just shows the toolbar but it does not show the login and signup component

Comment: @demkovych, if I add another dashboard layout with that it shows the main layout as well            
`<DashboardLayout>
 <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} exact />
</DashboardLayout>
`